# Regex to extract value of specific <input> tag

Tags: html, regex, jmeter

My goal is to use Regex to extract from an HTML document the value of a  tag with a specific name. The relevant part of the code is:

```
<!-- hidden datas -->
        <p class="hidden">
            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="6ac2c9b7d56b483ad6b9db051a285637" />
            <input type="hidden" name="id_product" value="541" id="product_page_product_id" />
            <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1" />
            <input type="hidden" name="id_product_attribute" id="idCombination" value="" />
        </p>
```

I'll need to extract the alphanumerical characters *6ac2c9b7d56b483ad6b9db051a285637*
Unfortunately, there is no other way than via Regex.

The same token is also present in another part of the document. Maybe it's easier to extract in that block of code?

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/webshop/js/tools.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var baseDir = '/webshop/';
        var static_token = '6ac2c9b7d56b483ad6b9db051a285637';
        var token = '1799f145490151b92137df1493a520cc';
        var priceDisplayPrecision = 2;
    </script>
```

Comment: you can use `jsoup` (http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Regular expression extractor component of JMeter for extracting string,
Expression will be,

```
static_token \= '(\w+)';

Template : $1$
Match no : 1
```

This should extract value in specified variable.

Comment: The good answer is the one by Dmitri T. Regexp is not good for HTML

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to get it using [XPath Extractor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) as follows:

1. Add XPath Extractor as a child of the request which returns that response
2. Add something meaningful as a `Reference Name` - it'll be a JMeter Variable name holding the result, i.e. `token`
3. If the response is not XHTML compliant check `Use Tidy` box
4. Use the following XPath expression in `XPath Query" input:

   ```
   //input[@name='token']/@value
   ```
5. Refer extracted value as `${token}` where required.

For more information on XPath language see the following resources:

- [XML Path Language (XPath) Version 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)
- [XPath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/)

Using Regex can also work, however in case of complex multiline HTML it is better to use XPath or [CSS/JQuery](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor) extractors. See the [famous answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748) for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will capture the token in your second example:

`/var static_token = '([0-9a-f]{32})';/`

Comment: The good answer is the one by Dmitri T. Regexp is not good for HTML

Answer (score 0):

JMeter documentation has a example that closely matches what you want to achieve:
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html

In your case:

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="([^"]+)" />
```

Comment: I wasn't able to figure out that part of the documentation at first, but now I get it. Thanks!

Comment: The good answer is the one by Dmitri T. Regexp is not good for HTML in JMeter